# How to target folding phone in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am build a Flutter app that i want to target phone like `Folding`, i have been having a problem each time my app get to `Samsung folding Phone`..

i want to be able to target folding phone, and use this package [Dual screen](https://pub.dev/packages/dual_screen) in some screen where needed.

i have try this but is not working

```
extension MediaQueryHinge on MediaQueryData {
  DisplayFeature? get hinge {
    for (final DisplayFeature e in displayFeatures) {
      if (e.type == DisplayFeatureType.hinge) {
        return e;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted is the same as what is on the [dualscreen MediaQuery docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dual-screen/flutter/mediaquery). You say it "isn't working". What exactly does that mean, do you get any error messages or it just always returns null?

Comment: @Wh1t3rabbit so when i use, **bool hasHinge = MediaQuery.of(context).hinge != null;** with the code it keep given *true* value even if i am another device... so with this, i come in conclusion to look for a way to target the device instead of the screen, with that it will very flexible for me to work around it...

Answer (score 0):

You have asked to retrieve an object so it does even if its null. Instead you want a bool flag. You could change the extension to a bool flag basis.